# Expand an element's height when positive free space is distributed (without JS)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height

Here is the base fiddle:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
}
header {
    background-color: red;
}
main {
    background-color: green;
}
footer {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lzhelenin/2j0yzuoe/

What I want is to make /main/ grow if there's enough free space 
http://joxi.ru/BA0dpaVcqQqMAy

I know that it's possible to do it using flexboxes:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute;
    align-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
header {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
main {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: green;
}
footer {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lzhelenin/2j0yzuoe/1/

The result looks exactly the way I want but I think it's not a really cross-browser solution. Is it possible to do it an another way (notice that I can't use fixed height)?

Comment: You mean like this ? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Not really. /Footer/ In your example has fixed height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy enough, you need one column of three rows, check my answer on question [how-to-build-flexible-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32656361/2015909).

Generally speaking:

- one flexible column (**display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-direction: column**)
- row one flexed child with fixed height (height: y-value-1)
- row two flexed child being stretched (**flex: 1**)
- row three flexed child with fixed height (height: y-value-2)

And if you want evenly distributed rows, make them all (**flex: 1**)