# How to build flexible structure?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to build a flexible structure with `CSS like this

[image]

TOP and BOTTOM `divs` have fixed height, while central box have responsive height. And all of them should cover the whole container div.

Can anyone tell me please how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% height div between header and footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322610/100-height-div-between-header-and-footer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy.

Basic html:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

and basic css:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.header, .footer {
    height:30px;
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
}
.main {
    height:calc(100% - 30px - 30px);
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
}
```

Just don't forget that when using "height" in % you need to include a fixed height in all parents of the element to make it work (in this case `body`and `html`)

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/ftncgbbb/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

```css
body{position: relative;padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
.top-sec{   background: #30a7fc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;}
.middle-sec{
  bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: initial;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000; color: #fff;
 }
.bottom-sec{
 background: #0000ff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 24px;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
 }
```

```html
<div class="top-sec"></div>
<div class="middle-sec">Please put here big data</div>
<div class="bottom-sec"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

These are the styles you need to use:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.header, .footer {
  /* don't grow, don't shrink, be 50px */
  flex: 0 0 50px;

  background: black;
}

.main {
  /* grow and shrink with the ratio of one */
  flex: 1 1;

  background: red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/horarivopo/1/edit?html,css,output

Although be aware of browser support (IE10+ w/ prefixes): http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units,flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example with CSS split for better understanding

Don't forget to vote and close the question, a lot of people tend to forget this, thanks.

```css
/* flexbox */        
main, header, footer, article   { display: flex }
main                            { justify-content: space-between; flex-direction: column }
article                         { flex: 1 }                         /* fill available space */

/* flexbox optional rule */
header, footer, article         { justify-content: center; align-items: center }

/* sizing */
html, body, main                { height: 100% }                    /* CSS needs to know how to fill */
main, header, footer, article   {  width: 100%; max-width: 100% }   /* max- for cross-browser quirks */
header, footer                  { height: 50px; line-height: 50px } /* same line-height centers text vertically */

/* styling */        
body                            { color: white; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
header, footer                  { background-color: black }
article                         { background-color: red }
```

```html
    <main>
        <header>some header</header>
        <article>some article</article>
        <footer>some footer</footer>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this-

```css
*{margin: 0;padding:0;}
    html, body {height: 100%;color:#fff;}
    header{height:50px;background: #000;position: absolute;top:0;width: 100%;}
    section {min-height: calc(100% - 50px);margin-bottom: -50px;background:red;padding-top:50px;}
    section:after {content: "";display: block;}
    footer, section:after {height: 50px; }
    footer{background: #000;}
```

```html
<header>
        Header
    </header>
    <section>
        Here is Content and all.
    </section>
    <footer>
        Footer
    </footer>
```