# How to cause a DIV to expand to fit between one element positioned absolute, and another element positioned fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page has one UL/LI at top, with the LIs positioned "relative", containing menu buttons.

Another div at the bottom positioned "fixed", containing links for help, copyright, terms of use, etc.

I have a div in between that I would like to stretch to fit between these two, such that it resizes with the browser window..

CSS:

```
.content {
    margin-left:1%;
}

ul.sdt_menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    width:1020px;
}
ul.sdt_menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}
ul.sdt_menu li{
    float:left;
    width:170px;
    height:85px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.sdt_menu li > a {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:170px;
    height:85px;
    z-index:12;
    background:transparent url(../images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
}
ul.sdt_menu li a img{
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:85px;
    z-index:100;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_wrap{
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:0px;
    width:170px;
    height:60px;
    z-index:15;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_active{
    position:absolute;
    background:#111;
    top:85px;
    width:170px;
    height:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:14;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link,
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr,
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
    margin-left:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr{
    color:#0B75AF;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:155px; /*For dumbass IE7*/
    font-size:10px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:340px;
    xoverflow:hidden;
    height:340px;
    top:85px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
    background:#000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#0B75AF;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:first-child{
    margin-top:15px;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Employment Application</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>


        <!-- The JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

        <style>
            body{
                background:#333 url(images/bg.jpg) repeat top left;
                font-family:Arial;
            }

            span.reference {
                position:fixed;
                left:10px;
                bottom:10px;
                font-size:12px;
            }

            span.reference a {
                color:#aaa;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
                margin-right:30px;
            }

            span.reference a:hover {
                color:#ff2222;
            }

            ul.sdt_menu {
                margin-top:80px;
            }

            h1.title {
                text-indent:-9000px;
                background:transparent url(images/title.png) no-repeat top right;
                width:633px;
                height:69px;
            }
        </style>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                /**
                * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
                * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
                * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
                * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
                * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
                */

                $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    $elem.find('img')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({
                            'width':'170px',
                            'height':'170px',
                            'left':'0px'
                         },400,'easeOutBack')
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_wrap')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_active')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function() {
                        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                        if($sub_menu.length){
                            var left = '170px';
                            if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                                left = '-170px';
                            $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},300);
                        }   
                    });
                }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length)
                        $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                    $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                         .andSelf().find('img')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({
                            'width':'0px',
                            'height':'0px',
                            'left':'85px'},400)
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_wrap')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h1 class="title">Employment Application</h1>
            <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/AboutUs.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">About Us</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Let's Get Started</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="sdt_box">
                            <a href="#">About US</a>
                            <a href="#">E-Verify</a>
                            <a href="#">Self Identification (Optional)</a>
                            <a href="#">How'd You Hear About Us? (Optional)</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/AboutYou.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">About You</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Just The basics</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="sdt_box">
                            <a href="#">1. About You</a>
                            <a href="#">2. Education</a>
                            <a href="#">3. Military Service</a>
                            <a href="#">4. Organisations</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">History</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Where You've Been</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">References</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Applicant Testimonials</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/5.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Finish</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Few last things and we're done</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content" style="color:white; margin-top:8px; float:left; width:70%; height:400px; overflow-y:auto; border:1px solid red; ">
            <br>
            <br>
            alskd fjlaksdj flaksdj flaksdj flkasdj flaksdjf lkasjdflkajsdlfk jalskdfj <br>
            alskd fjlaksdj flaksdj flaksdj flkasdj flaksdjf lkasjdflkajsdlfk jalskdfj <br>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span class="reference" style="border:1px solid green;">
                <a href="https://www.asdfasdf/apply/getHelp.html">Need Help?</a>
                <a href="https://www.asdfasdf/apply/termsOfUse.html">Terms of Use</a>
                <a href="">Site Design Copyright &copy; XYZ Company - All Rights Reserved</a>
            </span>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can this be done?

A CSS solution, or a javascript window sizing event will be fine, just so long as it can be done.

EDIT: Here is a pic of the current results:

[image: Current state]

**EDIT**: This is a modification of an excellent snippet I found here, and hat tip to http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/

Comment: Please update the code in your question as snippet (replace all relative links with absolute ones) and create a [mcve] of your problem. For example, you are linking a `.css` file, but only you know what it contains.

Comment: Simply use flexbox with one wrapper `flex-direction: column; align-content: space-between` holding 3 rows: header, content, footer with content `flex: 1`

Comment: See SO [How to build flexible structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605751/how-to-build-flexible-structure/32656361#32656361)

Comment: Andrei, thanks for your reply.  The CSS I posted IS the linked css.  Sorry, I should have mentioned.

Comment: Rene, I was unaware of flexbox, and on just a very quick look, it definitely looks like I will be able to use it to solve this problem.  Thanks.

Not sure if it could qualify as an answer, though, unless flexbox is part of the official CSS definition.  Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the body is not scrollable

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Your footer is:

```
bottom: 0px;
```

Make your content div

```
bottom: 20px; // or whatever is perfect
overflow: auto;
```

The footer will be fixed and because the body is not scrollable and the content is, the placement should always be right.

You could instead make your body scrollable with a margin:

```
margin-bottom: 20px;
```

And your footer:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

So that the body div scrolls and the footer is static.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I got TWO good answers, but I will mark this one as the answer because it's a pure CSS solution.  I only had to add a "top:260px" to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the JQuery route, how about this example that gets the offset bottom of `.sdt_menu` as well as the offset top of `.reference` and just makes the height of `.content` the difference between these two on resize.

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {

    var top = $('.sdt_menu').offset().top + $('.sdt_menu').outerHeight(true);
    var bottom = $(".reference").offset().top - 23;   
    var content_height = (bottom-top);

    $(".content:nth-child(2)").css("height", content_height); //I use nth-child(2) because you have multiple elements with class `.content`

}).resize() //so it resizes on load
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oez0488h/57/

Comment: You just answered with a copy of your previous answer please remove the duplicate

Comment: @Binvention Thanks, for some reason it left my original answer after I submitted an edit. Weird.

Comment: Sorry about that reuse of the "content" class.  I intend to change it to a unique identifier.

Comment: I liked that solution, too!  Thank you.